# Coverity scan skips all commands due to gcc -M option and scans nothing

Tags: c++, gcc, coverity

I am having some trouble using Coverity with my C/C++ code.

When I run `cov-build` with `--debug-flags translate-phases`, I get output that suggests that all compiler invocations are skipped because of the `-M` flag. Essentially (reading `build-log.txt` after running `cov-build`:

```
ARGS after split: -M -MP <other commands follow>
```

Then the next line:

```
Skipping command line '-M -MP <other commands follow>' because argument '-M' is a skip argument
```

This seems to result in Coverity not compiling any of my files and therefore produces no output.

Does Coverity simply not support the `-M` flag? Are there any workarounds?

For completeness I am using Coverity Scan 7.6.1 and gcc 4.8.2.

Comment: Yeah... Coverity is an awesome tool which has some documentation gaps :) Based on the log item *"... argument '-M' is a skip argument..."*, I'm guessing its not supported (but its only a guess). in the bigger picture: why are you asking Coverity to analyze the output of rules for Make dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer about two hours ago.

For me, the `cov-configure` command generated five different configuration artifacts (where 2-5 are folders):

1. Main configuration file
2. g++-config-0
3. g++-config-1
4. gcc-config-0
5. gcc-config-1

I don't really know why it decided to give me four folders, two for each type of compiler, but anyway.

In each of these four folders was a `coverity_configuration.xml` file. All of these contained the lines:

```
<skip_arg>-M</skip_arg>
<skip_arg>-MM</skip_arg>
```

Reading up on this tag, it tells the `cov-translate` command (called from `cov-build`) to not send to `cov-emit` any compiler invocation that passes either of those arguments. Removing those two lines solved everything.

I can't say why those two tags were put there by default. But it works now.

Comment: You have two for each - gcc as C, gcc as C++, g++ as C, g++ as C++

Comment: `-M` is a `skip_arg` because compilations with `-M` don't actually compile anything. You need subsequent *real* compilations, which Coverity will compile. This is what Paolo's answer said. Did you do a clean build? Perhaps the reason only the `-M` invocations were seen is because all your build artifacts were up-to-date and therefore `make` determined no compilations were needed (but the `-M` calls were still needed to ensure dependencies were up-to-date).

Comment: @Caleb I always did clean builds. The build process I'm working with is quite convoluted, and me not being very experienced in C/C++ build processes makes it difficult to decipher what is going on exactly. In any case though, removing those two tags made Coverity see my code, and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Passing `-M` to the compiler implies `-E`, i.e. run the preprocessor only.  Because of this, Coverity does not do anything at all here.  However, there's no reason why it shouldn't proceed with the *second* invocation of `gcc` that does not include `-M` and hence does compilation.

That said, there are better ways to automatically generate dependencies than the old `-M` flag; in particular newer versions of GCC allow you to do compilation and generation of dependencies with a single command. The relevant makefile idiom is this:

```
# the magic is all in this line
DEPFLAGS     = -MMD -MP -MT $@ -MF $(@D)/$(*F).d

# remember to change the spaces to tab here!
# anyway this is just an example.  All you need to do is to add
# $(DEPFLAGS) to your usual C compilation rule.
.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(DEPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

# same for C++
.cc.o:
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(DEPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

# at the end of the makefile, include the dependencies
-include $(wildcard *.d)
```

You may need something like `-include $(wildcard */*.d *.d)` if you have a nonrecursive Makefile.  But this part probably will be very similar to your existing rules.

This is described [here](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/#combine) and the linked web page will provide more information on automatic dependency generation than you thought could exist.

Comment: While your answer is interesting and I thank you for it, I am not at liberty to change the way the build process works in any way. So unfortunately this answer does not really help.

Comment: @Jokab But does your build process execute GCC a second time after the `-M` invocation? (I'm interested in the answer both with and without `cov-build`).