# Coverity skipping compilation commands with -MD

Tags: c++, coverity

Very similar to the issue described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38392029/coverity-scan-skips-all-commands-due-to-gcc-m-option-and-scans-nothing) - Coverity is skipping all compiler invocations because I'm passing `-MD` (w/o `-E`) to g++:

```
Skipping command line [...] because argument '-MD' is a skip argument
```

I am using `cov-translate` instead of `cov-build` to capture my builds, so Coverity probably is just not seeing the subsequent actual compilation here.

My question is how do I make `cov-translate` work in this situation? I cannot use `cov-build` and `-MD` must stay; in addition, I run my `cov-configure` in template mode, so editing the config XML to remove that `<skip_arg>-MD</skip_arg>` is a little tricky.

Thanks!

Comment: What coverity commands exactly are you running (specifically, what `cov-configure` and what `cov-translate` commands)? Running something like `cov-configure --gcc -c cfg/cfg.xml` (generate the "normal" gcc/g++ template configuration) followed by `cov-translate -c cfg/cfg.xml --dir idir g++ -MD main.cpp` using Coverity 2021.12.0 appears to work correctly and not skip the command line unless I manually add the the <skip_arg> to the generated config

Comment: Hi @LoganHunter, I'm running `cov-configure --config <...> --template-dir <...> --compiler g++arm --comptype dplus --template` and wrapping the native compilation command with`cov-translate --config <...> --dir <...> --run-compile "$@"`. The -MD skip arg seems to come by default as we don't specify any additional xml options.

Comment: (Apologies if that was confusing, the compiler is g++arm from Wind River. If this is actually pertinent detail I will update the question)

Comment: Running that cov-configure command without the --template-dir option generates a config without any <skip_arg>s in it, so I'd suspect that the templates in that directory are specifying that <skip_arg>-MD</skip_arg> should be used for that particular compiler/comptype set - you may have to edit the templates in the template directory (though depending on why that template-dir was set up, there may be a reason that the skip_arg was specified - I can't see the compiler manual for Wind River's compilers to know for sure if the -MD argument is the same as for vanilla gcc/g++)

Comment: That's a great pointer, our template dir always starts empty before build so that option is probably not doing anything. I also took a look at the default diab template shipped with Coverity and it's already has the -MD skip arg. So I guess my best bet is to in fact use a custom template file and remove that option? This is interesting though, Wind River toolchain doc indicates that flag works exactly the same way as with vanilla gcc/g++ so I wonder why it's to be skipped..

Comment: I missed that - yeah, -MD is a skip_arg for diab in the default templates. Setting up a --template-dir to override the default template for diab (replicating the config/templates directory from the coverity install) appears to work, but it is not clear why it was set in the first place - change that with caution, it might be wise to reach out to Coverity support for clarification.